# ASP .NET Core 6 dependency injection error with params keyword constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm migrating my project from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to ASP.NET Core 6.0.

I encounter a problem with the dependency injection when I try to register a class with a constructor containing params keyword. The actual error I received:

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> DotNet60DIWebApp.AuthorizePermission Lifetime: Scoped
> ImplementationType: DotNet60DIWebApp.AuthorizePermission': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'System.String[]' while attempting to
> activate 'DotNet60DIWebApp.AuthorizePermission'.)

The same code works in ASP .NET Core 2.1 but not in ASP .NET Core 6.0. Below is the code snippet which produces the error I encounter in ASP .NET Core 6.0.

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthorizePermission>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

**AuthorizePermission.cs**

```
namespace DotNet60DIWebApp
{
    public class AuthorizePermission
    {
        object[] Arguments;

        public AuthorizePermission(params string[] permissions)
        {
            Arguments = new object[] { permissions };
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I can't see how this ever worked. What strings were previously injected? I doubt it has anything to do with it being a `params` parameter, since that is really just syntactic sugar over creating an array.

Comment: _"he same code works in ASP .NET Core 2.1 but not in ASP .NET Core 6.0"_ are you sure this worked in "vanilla" 2.1 DI? Is there a possibility you are using some other IoC container?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way：

Define an interface `IAuthorizePermission` separately, and use `AuthorizePermission` as the implementation method of the interface,inject the `IAuthorizePermission` interface when using.

Below is my test code,you can refer it:

IAuthorizePermission:

```
public interface IAuthorizePermission
{
    object[] Arguments { get; }
    void Permission(params string[] permissions);
}
```

AuthorizePermission:

```
public class AuthorizePermission : IAuthorizePermission
{
    public object[] Arguments { get; set; }
    public  void Permission(params string[] permissions)
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { permissions };
    }
}
```

Program:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizePermission,AuthorizePermission>();
```

Controller:

```
private readonly IAuthorizePermission _authorizePermission;
public HomeController(IAuthorizePermission authorizePermission)
{
      _authorizePermission = authorizePermission;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
     _authorizePermission.Permission("Test1","Test2", "Test3");
     return View();
}
```

Test Result:
[image]